# Construct JavaScript object from cookie

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some data I am grabbing from a bunch of inputs, pushing to an array, saving to a cookie in JSON format and then reading back out again when the user next loads the page.

I want to populate an object with the data I read out of the cookie but can't figure out how to do it.

The data I have is `JSON.parse`'d so returns an array of objects. I want to then to be able to extract each object and add them as key value pairs to another object

i.e. go from:

`[{key1:value1},{key2:value2}...]`

to

`newObject = {key1:value1, key2:value2...}`

I will then use the new object to link to some knockout observables.

Any advice much appreciated. If you think there is a better way to construct the cookie data, I am open to suggestions, and if you need more info just let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var newObject = {};
array.forEach(function(obj) {
   for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          newObject[key] = obj[key];
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. I get an 'array is not defined error when I plug this in." I've created jsfiddle. Any chance you could put your solution in to show me how it integrates? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ocdcuvzv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  object_keys = Object.keys,

  list = [{key1: "value1"}, {key2: "value2"}, {key3: "value3"}],

  obj  = list.reduce(function (collector, item) {
    object_keys(item).forEach(function (key) {

      collector[key] = item[key]
    });
    return collector;
  }, {})
;
console.log(obj);
```